# Чем отличается добавление изображения через canvas?

Tags: javascript

Я что то не пойму. Видел некоторые когда добавляют изображения, меняют его размер через canvas. 
Чем это будет отличатся например от того, что я просто поменяю в свойствах img.style.width img.style.height?

Comment: cAnvas, а не cOnvas

Comment: может общую производительность после инициализации пытаются поднять, а может потому что считают что так принято, я такого ни разу сам не видел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для некоторых сложных задач простой CSS, разметка HTML, могут быть плохим решением. Поэтому прибегают к возможностям Canvas. Если задача заключается только в изменении размера изображения, то, для простоты, лучше, конечно, воспользоваться стандартными html-возможностями по установке высоты и ширины. Но существует ряд задач, которых сложно выполнить с помощью разметки и CSS. Тогда-то и будет более правильным использовать возможности Canvas. А то, что вы видели что кто-то где-то и каким-то образом что-то добавляет, так это, может, тому программисту так понятнее и легче, либо вы не до конца разобрали идею, почему именно так а не иначе было сделано. Иными словами, есть много разных способов, и каждый выбирает тот, который по его мнению легче. Вообще, всегда лучше не усложнять решение задач. И если вы видите, что легче и понятнее изменить размер при помощи img.style.width и img.style.height, то лучше так и делайте, не вдаваясь в дебри всяких там "крутых" технологий и каких-то "особых" решений. Чем вы проще и понятнее пишете код, тем вы более лучший программист, нежели тот, который заворачивает сложнейшие и закрученные схемы в простых задачах (что уж говорить о сложных, когда код легче переписать чем в нем разбираться :) ).